# How to automatically increment several Integer columns based on alphabetically ordered text columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, auto-increment

[image: Data table structure]

Hello and thank you very much in advance for taking the time to look at my question. My question is as followed, I have a large dataset in PostgreSQL, recorded in a similar fashion as it is written in the table.

The Province, District and Town column are constantly updated and new rows are added. I would like to have incremental numbers for the Province_id, District_id and Town_id automatically assigned whenever a new entry is made in one of the text columns. Preferablly, the numbers would update dynamically whenever a new Province, District or Town is entered (alphabetically).

Could I use triggers to make this automatically? I have also looked a lot at things like the dense_rank() functions (but is this a good method to follow?) I would be very happy to hear if there are alternative solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Why c-a-c is numbered 3-1-1 and not 3-1-2?

Comment: Different issue: why c-b-a is not numbered 3-2-3? Town IDs seem to restart per Province, not District.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, you are correct it should be 3-1-2, my mistake. Town IDs should restart per district, and could alphabetically. I changed that as well.

Comment: For a large table, renumbering a lot of rows when a new row is added won't scale well. What is the purpose of the ordering number?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, the combination of these numbers would be used as a Primary Key and Foreign Key in other tables. I agree it isn't a great solution for scaling but unfortunately its how a lot of our data is already structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption:

These ID values will only be used for output/display and will not be used as Unique Keys or in other tables (as Foreign Keys), otherwise you'll need a lot of cascade updates and loss of performance as a single row insert would result in updating a huge part of the table and many other tables as well.

Solution:

You don't have to store these values. You can use window functions, e.g. `DENSE_RANK()` to calculate these number when needed.

```
SELECT 
    province, district, town,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY province)
        AS province_id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY province
                       ORDER BY district)
        AS district_id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY province, district
                       ORDER BY town)
        AS town_id
FROM
    tableX AS t
 ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for me and I have recreated it in my own database (after I changed GROUP BY to PARTITION BY).

However, unfortunately my employer would like to have something like this as a Unique Key.  I convinced him that such design isn't scalable and therefore a flawed database design.  

Instead of trying to have alphabetic numbering, I will use increments based on new insert.  That way no previous rows need to be constantly updated. I have never worked with triggers before. Would you perhaps have any idea how I could make such an increment within a trigger?